# How can i combine two queries in sqlalchemy - raw and orm?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have these queries:

```
        funds_subq = text('''select distinct on (user_id) user_id,
last_value(amount) over(PARTITION BY user_id order BY id asc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
from transactions order by user_id, ts_spawn desc''')

    g1 = aliased(Group)
    u1 = aliased(User)
    users = Session.query(User.id.label('user_id'),
                          User.name.label('user_name'),
                          User.funds.label('user_funds'),
                          Group.id.label('group_id'),
                          Group.parent_id.label('parent_id'),
                          u1.id.label('owner_id'),
                          u1.name.label('owner_name')). \
        select_from(User). \
        join(Group, Group.id == User.group_id). \
        outerjoin(g1, g1.id == Group.parent_id). \
        outerjoin(u1, u1.id == g1.owner_id)
```

So, how can I join the first to the second? 
I tried something like this:

```
users = users.outerjoin(funds_subq, funds_subq.c.user_ud == User.id)
```

Of course, it did not worked, because funds_subq does not have `c` attribute and it does not have `subquery()` attribute too. 
And [that](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3049/support-range-specificaiton-in-window) issue shows that there is no way to use my version of the window query.

How can I implement my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about the question :)

There is my solution:

```
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


class Extreme(ColumnElement):

    def __init__(self, request_column, partition_by, order_by, last=True):
        super(Extreme, self).__init__()
        self.request_column = request_column
        self.partition_by = partition_by
        self.order_by = order_by
        self.last = last

    # @property
    # def type(self):
    #     return self.func.type


def extreme_last(request_column, partition_by, order_by):
    """
    function returns last_value clause like this:
        last_value(transactions.remains) OVER (
        PARTITION BY transaction.user_id
        order BY transactions.id asc
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    it returns last value of transaction.remains for every user, that means that we can get real balance of every user
    :param request_column: column, which last value we need
    :param partition_by: for what entity do we need last_value, e.g. user_id
    :param order_by: ordering for get last_value
    :return:
    """
    return Extreme(request_column, partition_by, order_by)


def extreme_first(request_column, partition_by, order_by):
    """
    as same as the `extreme_last` above, but returns first value
    :param request_column:
    :param partition_by:
    :param order_by:
    :return:
    """
    return Extreme(request_column, partition_by, order_by, last=False)


@compiles(Extreme)
def compile_keep(extreme, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "%s(%s) OVER (PARTITION BY %s order BY %s asc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)" % (
        "last_value" if extreme.last else "first_value",
        compiler.process(extreme.request_column),
        compiler.process(extreme.partition_by),
        compiler.process(extreme.order_by)
    )
```

And there is an example of using. The query returns `remains` field of the last row of every user:

```
Session.query(distinct(Transaction.user_id).label('user_id'),
                         extreme_last(Transaction.remains,
                                      partition_by=Transaction.user_id,
                                      order_by=Transaction.id).label('remains'))
```